# Show geotiff format images in openlayers map

Tags: openlayers, geoserver, geotiff, openlayers-5

I am new to Openlayers, and I have seen almost all examples and documentation ....
I have several .tiff format images, some have the same coordinates. I wanted to show these images at their coordinates on the front-end using angular 8.
I was just wondering how can I do it ? 
Do I need to use a server for sharing geospatial data like mapserver or geoserver ?
Or can I just transform my .tiff image to PNG and show it in its coordinates ?

Can you tell me what is the best approach ? Is there any examples ?

Comment: Unless you are planning to use only Internet Explorer you would need to convert to a format with wider browser support such as PNG.  Individual images could be displayed using an ImageStatic source or a custom variant such as http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/layer/map.geoimage.html  This discussion https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/4949 on using ImageStatic to display KML ground overlays might also be useful for other georeferenced images.

Comment: don't forget to accept the answer below assuming it works for you.  You get reputation points just for accepting the answer. additionally, it lets other know that the question has been answered correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to the stack overflow. Well, there are couple of ways to render geotiff images on web browser. First, there is one way that you mention it and it involves using middleware such as Geoserver or MapServer. Here are few helping starting point that will point you in the right direction:

- Here is rather general [Geoserver user manual](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/index.html)
- Or if u want more precise you can skip to the [WMS part](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/index.html)
- Some nice, step by step tutorial including OL and Geoserver [tutorial link](https://www.earder.com/tutorials/timeseries-with-geoserver-and-openlayers/)
- Some Udemy courses regarding OL and Geoserver [link](https://www.udemy.com/courses/search/?src=ukw&q=openlayers)
- OL Single image example https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wms-image.html

Next path is use use of [Geotiff.js library](https://geotiffjs.github.io/) along with [plotty](https://github.com/santilland/plotty). Here is little tutorial with explanation [Visualizing GeoTIFF Tiles with OpenLayers](https://eox.at/2018/01/visualizing-geotiff-tiles-with-openlayers/).

Also, [here](https://vueol.azurewebsites.net) is beta version of small WEB GIS app that includes uploading of GeoTIFF images functionality.

Hope it helps, enjoy :)